# How to receive intents flagged FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT

Tags: android, android-intent, service, hid

In Android 5.0 onwards, HidService.java includes following function:

```
private void broadcastReport(BluetoothDevice device, byte[] report, int rpt_size) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothInputDevice.ACTION_REPORT);
    intent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
    intent.putExtra(BluetoothInputDevice.EXTRA_REPORT, report);
    intent.putExtra(BluetoothInputDevice.EXTRA_REPORT_BUFFER_SIZE, rpt_size);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT);
    sendBroadcast(intent, BLUETOOTH_PERM);
}
```

I am not able to find any documentation on this flag in the intent. How should I receive this broadcast intent in my app?

==============
Edited content deleted and formed into new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232250/how-to-receive-bluetoothinputdevice-action-report-intents)

Comment: I was primarily worried that this flag will inhibit reception of Intents. As the answer clarifies, it only limits recipients during boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This constant is not documented in the [Intent API docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/content/Intent.html) because it is not intended for public use.

Here is a description from [the android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/135936072b24b090fb63940aea41b408d855a4f3/core/java/android/content/Intent.java) I found that describes it. (line 3018)

> **FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT**
>
> public static final int **FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT**
>
> If set, when sending a broadcast before boot has completed only registered receivers will be called -- no BroadcastReceiver components will be launched. Sticky intent state will be recorded properly even if no receivers wind up being called. If FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY is specified in the broadcast intent, this flag is unnecessary.
>
> **This flag is only for use by system sevices** as a convenience to avoid having to implement a more complex mechanism around detection of boot completion.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, all broadcast receivers will receive the intent *after* boot. I don't need to write a system service to receive this intent...

Comment: @GPS you cannot receive this intent in your app. It is only for android apps developed by google

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for taking time for responding. `BluetoothInputDevice.ACTION_REPORT` is basically just a string `"android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.REPORT"` and the way Intent is broadcast, it should require only `BLUETOOTH_PERM` which I should get with `"android.permission.BLUETOOTH"` in manifest. Is there anything else I missed that will prevent Intent from being received in my app?

Comment: @GPS I don't follow. Is this a new question? Anyway you should probably register your activity or whatever it is in the manifest as a `<receiver>` if you want to receive broadcasts

Comment: updated question. Added my broadcast receiver and manifest code. I don't see anything in the way Intent is sent that will disallow my code from receiving it, but my onReceive() is never called.

Comment: @GPS this is not really related to the question as it was before (when it was about `FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT`), I suggest you undo the edit and ask a new question about the new problem